# Solving ODE $xy' = y + xy^2$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm wondering how you would go about solving the following ODE:

$$xy' = y + xy^2 \quad ?$$

So far I've put it in the form,

$$y' - y/x - y^2 = 0$$

I'm not sure how to go from here as I can't factorise the $y$'s out and then find the integrating constant.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It is of the first order Bernoulli's form $y'+p\left(x\right)y=q\left(x\right)y^n\quad $: $y'-\frac{1}{x}y=y^2$ with $p\left(x\right)=-\frac{1}{x}, q\left(x\right)=1, n=2$.

Answer (score 3):

Use the formula $$ \left (\frac f g \right )'= \frac{f'g-fg'}{g^2}$$
$$xy' = y + xy^2 $$
$$xy' - y = xy^2 $$
Divide by $x^2$:
$$\left ( \frac y x \right )'=  \left (\frac {y^2} {x}\right )$$
It's separable:
$$\left ( \frac y x \right )'= x \left (\frac {y} {x}\right )^2$$

---

$$xy' - y = xy^2$$
Or divide by $y^2$ using the same formula:
$$ \left (\frac f g \right )'= \frac{f'g-fg'}{g^2}$$
$$-\left ( \frac x y \right )'= x$$
And integrate directly.

Answer (score 2):

Begin with
$$
xy' - y - xy^2 = 0
$$
Multiply by "integrating factor" $2/y^2$:
$$
\frac{2xy'}{y^2} - \frac{2}{y}  - 2x= 0
$$
Note that this is exact:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(-\frac{2x}{y} - x^2\right) = 0
$$
so
$$
-\frac{2x}{y} - x^2 = C
$$
and thus
$$
y = \frac{2x}{C-x^2} .
$$

Comment: There's also the null solution $y=y(x)=0, \forall x\in(a,b)$. +1

Comment: To get $0$ solution, you have to allow $C=\infty$.

Comment: Starting from the initial ODE. If $y=0 \rightarrow 0=0$.

Comment: This is correct. The differential equation is singular at $x=0$ and here the solution is not unique. One could also have solutions like $y(x) = \max\{0,\frac{2x}{C-x^2}\}$ or $y(x) = \min\{0,\frac{2x}{C-x^2}\}$ that satisfy the equation almost everywhere and are continuous, but the notion of a weak/distributional solution is needed to make this rigorous.